# Event Binding in Dynamic Elements With Complex Selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

I have the current selector for non-dynamic `click` events:

```
$( "#names > tbody > tr, .projcontainer > tbody > tr:not(:first)")
```

How do I put this in an `on` bind event for dynamically loaded contents? I tried this and it (expectedly) didn't work:

```
$( "#names > tbody > tr, .projcontainer > tbody > tr:not(:first)" ).on("dblclick", function() {
            loadPerson($(this).children().first().text());
        });
```

I know that in previous examples I have had to do normal click events like this:

```
$("#names").on("click", "tr", ....
```

But I'm not sure how to translate that with more complex selectors..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for your dynamically injected elements.

```
$(document).on("dblclick", 
              "#names > tbody > tr, .projcontainer > tbody > tr:not(:first)",function() {
      console.log('event happened');
});
```

Comment: Stackoverflow does it again! Thanks - will tick the answer when SO lets me!

Comment: Keep in mind, it is suggested to use the document body when binding (not just straight document), and also if you could anchor this whole thing (i.e. bind to a closer element) it will decrease the possibility for future performance hits.